# Passing an array as `params` argument

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

I have the following method:

```
void MyMethod(params object[] args)
{
}
```

which I am trying to call with a parameter of type `object[]`:

```
object[] myArgs = GetArgs();
MyMethod(myArgs);
```

It compiles fine, but inside `MyMethod` I `args == { myArgs}`, i.e. an array with one element that is my original arguments. Obviously I wanted to have `args = myArgs`, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Jon Skeet was actually right, the `GetArgs()` did wrap the thing in an one element array, sorry for stupid question.

Comment: _"but inside MyMethod I args == { myArgs}"_ What does this mean? Why don't you show that code?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it means:  i.e. an array with one element that is my original arguments.

Comment: The problem `object[]` is `object` too :)

Comment: @Grzenio: my question  remains unanswered, why don't you show the code in the method?

Comment: [The mysterious ways of the params keyword in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/06/10439573.aspx)

Comment: @Hans: No, this isn't entirely normal at all. That's *not* what happens. The compiler won't create an array when it doesn't need to.

Comment: Does `GetArgs()` return an `object[]`?

Comment: what .net version you use?

Comment: @DStanley, yes, it does return `object[]`, with 3 elements in this particular case.

Comment: Note however, that if you try to do something like `MyMethod(newObject, newObjectArray)`, it won't collapse the array and merge it with the object, you'll get another array whose first item is an `object` and whose second item is an `object[]`.

Comment: @Grundy, .Net version in 4.0

Comment: @Grzenio I'm not able to reproduce your problem.  Either you're wrapping the `object[]` into an `object` yourself somewhere or something else is doing it implicitly.  If you can strip down your code to a bare minimum that reproduces the problem it may resolve itself.

Comment: @Grzenio can you show your GetArgs() method?

Comment: @peer i'm not an OP :-)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What you've described simply doesn't happen. The compiler does *not* create a wrapper array unless it needs to. Here's a short but complete program demonstrating this:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void MyMethod(params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        object[] args = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
        MyMethod(args);
    }
}
```

According to your question, this would print 1 - but it doesn't, it prints 3. The value of `args` is passed directly to `MyMethod`, with no further expansion.

Either your code isn't as you've posted it, or the "wrapping" occurs within `GetArgs`.

You can *force* it to wrap by casting `args` to `object`. For example, if I change the last line of `Main` to:

```
MyMethod((object) args);
```

... *then* it prints 1, because it's effectively calling `MyMethod(new object[] { args })`.

Comment: `MyMethod(new int[]{1,2,3})` prints `1`, so maybe it's not an object[] array.

Comment: @Dirk: Yes, because an `int[]` isn't an `object[]`. It has to wrap it. That's not what the OP's code shows - the compile-time type of `myArgs` is `object[]`, not `int[]`.

Comment: @Dirk Yes, that's because int is a value type and thus cannot be used as an object array

Comment: @Dirk new int[] != new object[], your types are not maching

Comment: I know, I meant that could be the cause of the OP's problem, if he used `var array = GetArgs()` for instance.

Comment: @All I think Dirk understands the distinction, he was simply raising a possible reason why the OPs code doesn't do what it says on the tin.

Comment: @peer The types do not necessarily have to match exactly, but the element type has to be a reference type. A `string[]` for example works.

Comment: @Dirk: Well in that case the code isn't as posted, as I state in my answer. Unfortunately, at that point it could be different in any number of ways :(

Comment: @Jon You're the genius. I don't know how someone can acquire this much knowledge.

Comment: @JonSkeet what if you'd like to accept `params object[]`, but send different types? That wouldn't work, right? From what I read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params it's basically AS IS.

Comment: @eestein: I'm afraid I don't understand what scenario you're describing. If you're interested in pursuing this further, I suggest you ask a new question with more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure, I've already figured it out anyway. But now that I read my message again, I understand the confusion :D thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

The following conversion works for me:

```
void Foo(params object[] args)
{
  foreach (var arg in args) 
    Console.WriteLine(arg.ToString());
}

var integers = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
Foo(integers.Cast<object>());
```

The reason we have to do this is because `int[]` is `object`. Therefore it would pass it as argument `[0]` in the `params object[]` array. If you use the extension `.Cast<object>()` method, it will transform the argument to a `object[]` which will allow it to directly pass into the args.

This little nuance makes accepting `params object[]` difficult because there is no compiler warning or error to help restrict the inputs to the use the writer *intended*.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**